# VBA Cells(i,5).Text

Tags: vba, excel

I'm new to VBA-programming and got some issues with this code.. It is to check, whether a storage place exists and if this place has an article assigned to it.. It already worked, but now it wont do 'If Cells(i, 5).Text Is Nothing' and therefore the GoTo-line jumps in..

If Cells(i,5).Value isn't working as well..

Any help appreciated.

```
Dim x As String
Dim z As String
Dim i As Integer

Tabelle3.Activate

x = InputBox("Please insert the storage place, that is to be emptied")
Cells(3, 2) = x

i = 1
On Error GoTo Ende
Do Until ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 5) = x Or i = 10 'i=amount of available storage places
i = i + 1
Loop

On Error GoTo Ende
If Cells(i, 5).Text Is Nothing Then
Exit Sub
ElseIf ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6).Value Is Nothing Then
MsgBox "This storage place has no article in it!"
Exit Sub
Else
z = ""
Cells(i, 6) = z
MsgBox "Emptying the storage place " & ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 6) & " was successfull"
End If

Ende:
If Err.Number Then
MsgBox "This storage place doesn't exists or was entered incorrectly"
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: BTW. Using `On Error GoTo Ende` statement twice in a sub is not nescessary. `On Error` is valid for the full time the code is being executed. For the program to be more understandable with its behavior you should always put `On Error` statement to the beginning of you sub or function and if you still have errors in your code DO NOT USE it until you are absolutely sure turning off errors is safe or is intentional. This problem would have solved itself if you had let the compiler tell you where there is an error.

Comment: Also, to help you on your way - consider using `Debug.Print` and immediate window to check if your statement gives you the result you want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Is Nothing` is for objects.

If you want to check whether a cell is empty you could

`If Len(cells(1,1)) = 0 then`

or

`If IsEmpty(cells(1,1)) then`

or

`If cells(1,1) = vbNullString`

And!

be careful using the `.Text` property because if you have had for example a date or a number in a cell and the column width was a low value and the contents wouldn't fit and display `##` then `.Text` would return `##` instead of the actual value. WYSIWYG

Comment: + 1 For cells which may have spaces and you want to consider them as well then one can also use `if(len(trim(cells(1,1).Value))=0 then`